# URL Rewrite Issue (PHP - Apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

```
RewriteRule ^türkçe/yazılar/(.+)$ sayfa.php?rd_dil=türkçe&rd_sayfa=yazılar&rd_yazar=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^türkçe/yazılar/(.+)/(.+)$ sayfa.php?rd_dil=türkçe&rd_sayfa=yazılar&rd_yazar=$1&rd_baslik=$2 [L]
```

first rule works fine with both url structure. (with seo friendly and with conventional)
second rule only works with conventional structure. I couldn't make **`localhost/türkçe/yazılar/drogba/karakter`**
Can you show me my mistake please?
thanks, best regards

Comment: you should put second to top, because second query enter to first now

Comment: sanj is right. Alternatively, you can use `([^/]+)` instead of `(.+)`.